# FIle Not Found exception while deploying Jar

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I am getting File not found Exception to access files in File object from jar deployed after successful compilation.In this case files are placed in default folder of src and being access via **src/filename.txt**.

Even tried MyClass.class.getResource("/file.txt").getPath(); to access file
[image: Dir Structure]

```
File filterFile=new File("win.txt");
File currentFile=new File("winP.txt");
```

Kindly provide suggestion i.e. where to place text file in netbeans for jar deployment.

Comment: Would be easier if you don't hide the names of your classes and packages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between files and resources. Every file is also a resource, but not vice versa. Inside a JAR file, you do not have files, but only resources.

Loading resources is also done with a class loader. So you must first retrieve a class loader, then load the resource with it:

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL resourceUrl = loader.getResource(resourceName);
try (InputStream in = resourceUrl.openStream()) {
    // load bytes from the input stream here
}
// process the loaded resource bytes here
```

Now where to place the files? You could either place them into the root of the JAR. Inside your project, that means to place the resource file into the folder `src`. Or you place them into a package to have them beside the class that needs it.

If placed into the root, you access them via the resource name, only. If placed into a subdirectory (a package), you must prefix the resource name with that path - beginngin from the root. Example:

```
URL resourceUrl = loader.getResource("my/pkg/win.txt");
```

Just a convenience: If the resource file is placed into the same package as the class that is needing that resource, you could also use the class itself for loading (and not the class loader):

```
URL resourceUrl = getClass().getResource("win.txt");
```

Note, that in this case, the directory structure is omitted.

In your example, you created a file object. If you used that file object to create a `FileInputStream` later, then you can just use the `InputStream`, which I described above, instead of that.

Comment: Thanks Sir.It really help me out.But when I am trying to execute run time powershell command from java to execute a power shell script.I get ** powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -noprofile -noninteractive /D:/Workspaces/Netbeans%20Projects/Project/src/res/PName.ps1**. But this is invalid. I want to get path of script file so that jar can get it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. Normally, you run JAR files from a console with "java -jar <jar-file>".

Comment: I am using web start to launch jar file from tomcat.

Comment: Hmmm ... file in jar ... netbeans ... powershell ... web launch ... tomcat ... executionpolicy ... remotesigned ... What - the hell - are you doing? Are you trying to access a resuorce inside your JAR, or are you trying something else? Seriously, if you do not know how to use your tools, then you should go some steps back and start over. Start with writing a simple Java application that can be started from the command line (like I told you above). If anything else fails, start new questions. Honestly, the last information should already have been placed in your original question.